# Check whether a column is loaded from a 3rd table correctly

Tags: sql, hive

First of apologies if this question is too basic as im still a beginner

I have 3 tables a,b and c

- table a has 2 columns tr_id, cp_id
- table b has tr_id, cde
- table c has
  cde, value

condition to load a.cp_id is

> { case when b.cde = "some_value" then a.cp_id = c.value else NULL }

how do i write a query to check whether the **a.cp_id** is loaded correctly as per the above condition

Comment: Is this for a `update`? What's the relationship between the tables? Please provide some sample data.

Comment: not for update, this is for data validation. relationship is a.tr_id=b.tr_id and b.cde=c.cde